# Using loop EIP to solve a Usecase in Apache Camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I have a usecase in which I have a route which takes m number of rest URLS' as input and then hits each of these URLS's n number of times each until response code comes out to be 204.

So hit a URL until 204 is response code and if it returns 204 move on to next URL and apply same procedure.

I tried to use loop EIP but it did not work.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, something like this should do the trick:

```
<from uri="bean:cxf...." />

<setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
<to uri="jetty...." /> //hit the url

<choice>
  <when>
    <simple>CHECK_IF_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_HEADER_IS_204</simple>
    <to uri="mock:result" />
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    <to uri="bean:cxf...." /> //send the exchange to this very route again
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```